# HTML/CSS transparent border indent, z-index

Tags: html, css, background, border, z-index

Coding a header to a website which will look like this:

[image]

Having problems creating the 5px indent under the "People" link, which is intended to indicate the active/current page. I know how to "fake" this effect by using background images/colors, etc -- but the content underneath is going to be different on each page (sometimes a solid color, sometimes the background pattern shown in the example, sometimes a photo). So that indent needs to be transparent.

I'm assuming I'll use z-index to overlay this header over whatever content will be underneath. Just can't figure out how to get a transparent indent in *only* one section while *also* having the grey menu bar continue to be 100% browser width. Probably something simple that I've overlooked. Thanks.

Edit: working JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonpeat/mVSBj/14/

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="ombre">
    <div id="ombre1"></div>
    <div id="ombre2"></div>
    <div id="ombre3"></div>
    <div id="ombre4"></div>
    <div id="ombre5"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://asheragency.com/websites/asher2014/asher_logo.png" alt="Asher" id="asherLogo"/>
<ul>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your working code? A jsFiddle would be nice

Answer (score 0):

not very elegant but here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/cke6U/1/

there's no way you can produce a 5px "hole" in your background, my solution needs the `li` element to have a background (not the `header` or the `ul`) so that may not suit you

you basically have to play with `height` on `:hover`

```
li {list-style:none;float:left;height:50px;line-height:50px;width:16.66666666666667%;text-align:center;position:relative;background:grey}

li:hover {height:45px}
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of playing with bottom-border but your height solution is great. That solves all my problems but one: how to handle the overall background of the header.Here's a fiddle with your fixes implemented (http://jsfiddle.net/brandonpeat/mVSBj/14/) -- you can see how that grey bar shows through. I just need to figure out how to pull that bar back in just that li section.

Comment: Really close! I just need the header content (logo, li links) confined to a central 940px area, while that grey bar stretches to 100% at all times. (This is the part that's driving me crazy!) http://jsfiddle.net/brandonpeat/mVSBj/17/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. Check out this previous fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/brandonpeat/mVSBj/14/) and resize the screen extra wide to see what I'm talking about. The grey bar needs to always be 100% width, but the content inside the bar (logo, links) needs to stay in the 940px area. Sorry to be so picky, that's why it's stumping me!